# Numbered argument from pipe

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Can anyone explain me why second awk doesn't work?

```
echo 1 2 3 4 |  echo "`awk '{print $1,$2}'`, `awk '{print $3,$4}'`"
gives me result:
1 2,
```

Is there another way to get numbered arguments from pipe? I tried use xargs, but it returns all arguments. In a script I can relate to argument using `echo $1` but from pipe it doesn't work.

Comment: Because the first awk consumes the entire input, leaving nothing for the 2nd awk to read.

Comment: Why are you using `awk` inside `echo`?

Comment: I'm surprised the whole thing doesn't just hang with the first awk called by echo waiting for input. What are you REALLY trying to do?

Comment: This is a totally wrong approach to a problem as the other write.  You should also get rid of old and outdated back-tics and use parentheses like this. `echo "$(awk '{print $1,$2}')"`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to launch two programs for each input line having 4 args like `something 1 2` and `something2 3 4`. You can do with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) on the following way:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 | awk '{system("something "$1" "$2); system("something2 "$3" "$4);}'
```

A test:

```
echo -e "1 2 3 4\n11 22 33 44" | awk '{system("/bin/echo A "$1" "$2); system("/bin/echo B "$3" "$4);}'
```

Output:

```
A 1 2
B 3 4
A 11 22
B 33 44
```

Or if you want to format the four args somehow and launch only one other program, you can do it similarly, but it can be done in the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) command line as well.

Or of course Glenn's solution can be used in a loop like:

```
echo -e "1 2 3 4\n11 22 33 44"|while read -r -a a; do
  something ${a[0]} ${a[1]}; something2 ${a[2]} ${a[3]}
done
```

or

```
while read -r -a a; do
  something ${a[0]} ${a[1]}; something2 ${a[2]} ${a[3]}
done < <(echo -e "1 2 3 4\n11 22 33 44")
```

(mind the space between `<` characters)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: just use the shell's `read` command

```
read a b c d <<END
1 2 3 4
END
echo "$a $b, $c $d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to capture `stdin` as numbered positional parameters inside a pipe:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 | { read; set -- $REPLY; echo "A $1 $2"; echo "B $3 $4"; }
A 1 2
B 3 4
```

#### How it works

- `{`

  This starts a group.  The group allows us to execute several statements together inside the pipeline.  A space must follow the `{`.
- `read`

  The shell builtin `read` takes a line of stdin and assigns it to the variable `REPLY`.
- `set -- $REPLY`

  `set` is another shell builtin.  It is used to assign the strings in `REPLY` to shell's positional parameters: `$1`, `$2`, *etc.*

  The dash-dash after `set` is used to indicate the end of options.  This guarantees that what follows is treated as arguments, not options, even if it happened to begin with a dash.
- `echo "A $1 $2"; echo "B $3 $4";`

  This demonstrates that we have successfully assigned the positional parameters.
- `}`

  This closes the group.  A space and semicolon (or just a line break) must precede the `}`.

The above sets the positional parameters only for the duration of the `{...}` group.

#### Alternative

Suppose that you want to keep the numbered positional parameters even after the pipeline ends.  In that case:

```
read < <(echo 1 2 3 4)
set -- $REPLY
echo "A $1 $2"
echo "B $3 $4"
```

This produces the output:

```
A 1 2
B 3 4
```

### Why the two awks didn't work

Consider:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 |  echo "`awk '{print $1,$2}'`, `awk '{print $3,$4}'`"
1 2,
```

When the first `awk` command runs, it consumes all of stdin.  Wehn the second `awk` command runs, there is not input left for it to process.

It might be more clear if we simplify the above command, removing the `echo` and the command substitution:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 |  { awk '{print $1,$2","}'; awk '{print $3,$4}'; }
1 2,
```

Let's print out the complete input lines that each `awk` sees:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 |  { awk '{print "first="$0;}'; awk 'BEGIN{print "2nd awk starting"}{print "second="$0}'; }
first=1 2 3 4
2nd awk starting
```

The first `awk` reads all the input.  The second `awk` sees no input at all.